# React Native suddenly fail to build

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux

So, I was doing some modification on my code this morning and it runs just like it used to. And then when I tried to run react-native run-android again after few hours, I got below error:

> /Users/mimicreative/Documents/Kerja/Project/PictalogiDev/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/res/layout/abc_action_bar_title_item.xml:21:22-76: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TitleItem').
>
> /Users/mimicreative/Documents/Kerja/Project/PictalogiDev/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/res/layout/abc_action_bar_title_item.xml:30:41-91: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginTop' with value '@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_top_margin_material').
>
> /Users/mimicreative/Documents/Kerja/Project/PictalogiDev/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.0.0/res/layout/abc_action_bar_view_list_nav_layout.xml:22:22-48: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?attr/actionBarTabBarStyle').

So much line of error like above then at the end of the line I got this:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

How can I fix this? What causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, you just need to update the **Android Support Repository** using Android SDK Manager.